# Test rails controller that respond in different formats

Tags: ruby-on-rails, automated-tests

I have the following function in controller

```
def by_xy
        @obj = BldPoly::find_by_xy(:x => params['x'], :y => params['y'])

        respond_to do |format|
            format.html { render :layout => false  }
            format.xml { render :layout => false }
            format.json { render :layout => false }
end
```

and planning to write the automatic test in the following way

```
xml = nil
get :by_xy, {:x => 4831, :y => 3242, :format => :json} 
assert_nothing_thrown { xml = REXML::Document.new(@response.body) }

td = REXML::XPath.first(xml, "//result/item")
assert_equal need_value, td.value
```

and I get 
Completed in 50ms (View: 0, DB: 230) | 406 Not Acceptable [http://test.host/search/by_xy/4831/3242.json]

when I missed format in testing code - all works correctly,

how should I write the test?

Answer (score 9):

I figured this out, actually; this is how it should be

```
get :by_xy, {:x => i[:x], :y => i[:y]}, :format => :json
```

Comment: Not sure if this worked at one point, but it doesn't seem to anymore.

Comment: The hash used for :x, and :y is the problem, remove the hash. So, you'll have something like: `get :action, param1: 'a', param2: 'b', format: :json`

Answer (score 4):

For rails 5.1, when doing a post, I had to include the `format` attribute inside of my params hash

```
share_params = {
  email: nil,
  message: 'Default message.'
  format: :json
}
post image_share_path(@image), params: share_params
assert_response :unprocessable_entity
```

If not I would get the error `ActionController::UnknownFormat` inside of my create controller

```
def create
  @image = Image.new(image_params)
  if @image.save
    flash[:success] = 'Your image was saved successfully.'
    redirect_to @image
  else
    respond_to do |format|
      format.json do
        render json: { @image.to_json }, 
        status: :unprocessable_entity
      end
  end
end
```

Comment: Same here, this must be due to the introduction of [keyword arguments](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/18323/) in Rails 5+. Additionally Rails might throw a `ActionController::InvalidCrossOriginRequest` security warning for Ajax requests. Can be solved using `xhr: true` with the request method (not within the params) : `get url, params: { format: :js }, xhr: true`